# Фатальная ошибка при смене шрифта array

Tags: php, массивы, wordpress

Я пытаюсь изменить шрифт заголовка на сайте WordPress. Выдает сообщение об ошибке:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: implode(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array, string given in /home/solace/domains/remont-priemka.ru/public_html/wp-content/themes/renowise/bold-page-builder/content_elements/bt_bb_headline/bt_bb_headline.php:62 Stack trace: #0 /home/solace/domains/remont-priemka.ru/public_html/wp-content/themes/renowise/bold-page-builder/content_elements/bt_bb_headline/bt_bb_headline.php(62): implode(Array, '; ') #1 /home/solace/domains/remont-priemka.ru/public_html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(356): bt_bb_headline->handle_shortcode(Array, '', 'bt_bb_headline') #2 [internal function]: do_shortcode_tag(Array) #3 /home/solace/domains/remont-priemka.ru/public_html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(228): preg_replace_callback('/\[(\[?)(bt_bb_...', 'do_shortcode_ta...', '[bt_bb_headline...') #4 /home/solace/domains/remont-priemka.ru/public_html/wp-content/plugins/bold-page-builder/content_elements/bt_bb_column_inner/bt_bb_column_inner.php(171): do_shortcode('[bt_bb_headline...') #5 /home/solace/domains/remont-priemka.ru/public_html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(356): bt_bb_column_inner->handle_shortcode(Array, '[bt_bb_headline...', 'bt_bb_column_in...') #6 [internal function]: do_shortcode_tag(Array) #7 /home/solace/domains/remont-priemka.ru/public_html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(228): preg_replace_callback('/\[(\[?)(bt_bb_...', 'do_shortcode_ta...', '[bt_bb_column_i...') #8 /home/solace/domains/remont-priemka.ru/public_html/wp-content/plugins/bold-page-builder/content_elements/bt_bb_row_inner/bt_bb_row_inner.php(45): do_shortcode('[bt_bb_column_i...') #9 /home/solace/domains/remont-priemka.ru/public_html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(356): bt_bb_row_inner->handle_shortcode(Array, '[bt_bb_column_i...', 'bt_bb_row_inner') #10 [internal function]: do_shortcode_tag(Array) #11 /home/solace/domains/remont-priemka.ru/public_html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(228): preg_replace_callback('/\[(\[?)(bt_bb_...', 'do_shortcode_ta...', '[bt_bb_row_inne...') #12 /home/solace/domains/remont-priemka.ru/public_html/wp-content/plugins/bold-page-builder/content_elements/bt_bb_column/bt_bb_column.php(174): do_shortcode('[bt_bb_row_inne...') #13 /home/solace/domains/remont-priemka.ru/public_html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(356): bt_bb_column->handle_shortcode(Array, '[bt_bb_row_inne...', 'bt_bb_column') #14 [internal function]: do_shortcode_tag(Array) #15 /home/solace/domains/remont-priemka.ru/public_html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(228): preg_replace_callback('/\[(\[?)(bt_bb_...', 'do_shortcode_ta...', '[bt_bb_column w...') #16 /home/solace/domains/remont-priemka.ru/public_html/wp-content/plugins/bold-page-builder/content_elements/bt_bb_row/bt_bb_row.php(71): do_shortcode('[bt_bb_column w...') #17 /home/solace/domains/remont-priemka.ru/public_html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(356): bt_bb_row->handle_shortcode(Array, '[bt_bb_column w...', 'bt_bb_row') #18 [internal function]: do_shortcode_tag(Array) #19 /home/solace/domains/remont-priemka.ru/public_html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(228): preg_replace_callback('/\[(\[?)(bt_bb_...', 'do_shortcode_ta...', '[bt_bb_row colu...') #20 /home/solace/domains/remont-priemka.ru/public_html/wp-content/plugins/bold-page-builder/content_elements/bt_bb_section/bt_bb_section.php(193): do_shortcode('[bt_bb_row colu...') #21 /home/solace/domains/remont-priemka.ru/public_html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(356): bt_bb_section->handle_shortcode(Array, '[bt_bb_row colu...', 'bt_bb_section') #22 [internal function]: do_shortcode_tag(Array) #23 /home/solace/domains/remont-priemka.ru/public_html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(228): preg_replace_callback('/\[(\[?)(bt_bb_...', 'do_shortcode_ta...', '<div class="bt_...') #24 /home/solace/domains/remont-priemka.ru/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): do_shortcode('<div class="bt_...') #25 /home/solace/domains/remont-priemka.ru/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(189): WP_Hook->apply_filters('<div class="bt_...', Array) #26 /home/solace/domains/remont-priemka.ru/public_html/wp-includes/post-template.php(253): apply_filters('the_content', '[bt_bb_section ...') #27 /home/solace/domains/remont-priemka.ru/public_html/wp-content/themes/renowise/page.php(7): the_content() #28 /home/solace/domains/remont-priemka.ru/public_html/wp-includes/template-loader.php(106): include('/home/solace/do...') #29 /home/solace/domains/remont-priemka.ru/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('/home/solace/do...') #30 /home/solace/domains/remont-priemka.ru/public_html/index.php(17): require('/home/solace/do...') #31 {main} thrown in /home/solace/domains/remont-priemka.ru/public_html/wp-content/themes/renowise/bold-page-builder/content_elements/bt_bb_headline/bt_bb_headline.php on line 62

Я не понимаю, что случилось. У меня php 8.

Вот файл, в котором должна быть ошибка:
https://gist.github.com/marselsol/ce5198f51398f6b7644add370b394275

```
$html_tag_style = "";
        $html_tag_style_arr = array();
        if ( $font != '' && $font != 'inherit' ) {
            $el_style = $el_style . ';' . 'font-family:\'' . urldecode( $font ) . '\'';
            $html_tag_style_arr[] = 'font-family:\'' . urldecode( $font ) . '\'';
        }
        if ( $font_size != '' ) {
            $html_tag_style_arr[] = 'font-size:' . $font_size  ;
        }
        if ( count( $html_tag_style_arr ) > 0 ) {
            $html_tag_style = ' style="' . implode( $html_tag_style_arr, '; ') . '"';
        }
```

Что нужно поправить в этом файле, чтобы эта ошибка не вылезала?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Я не понимаю, что случилось. У меня php 8.

У вас случилось неправильное использование функции `implode()`, как, собственно, и указано в сообщении об ошибке:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: implode(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array, string given in /home/solace/domains/remont-priemka.ru/public_html/wp-content/themes/renowise/bold-page-builder/content_elements/bt_bb_headline/bt_bb_headline.php:62

Смотрим что у нас в строке 62:

```
$html_tag_style = ' style="' . implode( $html_tag_style_arr, '; ') . '"';
```

Обращаемся к [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php) функции implode():

> implode(string $separator, array $array): string

То есть функция принимает сначала строковый разделитель, а затем уже массив.

> Устаревшая сигнатура (устарела с PHP 7.4.0, удалена в PHP 8.0.0):
> implode(array $array, string $separator): string

Т. к. у вас версия php 8.0, то ваш вариант использования функции недопустим, замените его на корректный

Comment: "замените его на корректный" подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать? На что заменить эту строку?

Comment: @Mars тебе же даже ссылку дали - найди в себе сила почитать хоть маны, если ошибку неосилил.

Comment: @Mars поменяйте местами аргументы, которые передаёте в функцию. Вместо `implode( $html_tag_style_arr, '; ')` будет `implode('; ', $html_tag_style_arr)`

Comment: @alenkins спасибо большое! Заработало!) Я не знаю как отметить ваш ответ "Полезным" и "Решающим проблему" :(

Comment: @Mars серая галочка под рейтингом ответа (слева вверху от текста ответа), нажимаете её и ответ принимается